# How to get the backend/api roles to manage the authorization views with React?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, database, api, roles

I'm building a system which it backend has roles, like admin, partner... how can I verify the user role on every view and disable its components?

I've been trying to make a request on every view, getting the role, but I guess it can make my system slower after a time.